# How to get x -coordinates and y- coordinates on tap in bokeh

Tags: python, callback, bokeh, tap

I am facing problem with how to show  x and y coordinates on graph in bokeh using Tap tool

I have tried following code. Now i want to write a call back for tap tool how do i do that. how do i show  on clicking the square the x an y coordinates

```
  from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, OpenURL, TapTool
  from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

  output_file("openurl.html")

  p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
               tools="tap", title="Click the Dots")

  source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 
                         7]))


  p.square('x', 'y', color='green', size=20, source=source)

  taptool = p.select(type=TapTool)

  show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the x and y coordinates on tap by writing a callback that is called when the selection changes. The indexes of the currently selected glyphs can be found in source.selected.indices. These indexes can be used to get the x and y coordinates from source.data. This piece of code prints the x and y coordinates in the console in your browser (F12).

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, TapTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("openurl.html")

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
             tools="tap", title="Click the Dots")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7]))

p.square('x', 'y', color='green', size=20, source=source)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var selectedIndex = source.selected.indices;
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedIndex.length; i++) {
        console.log("Index:", selectedIndex[i]);
        console.log("x:", source.data['x'][selectedIndex[i]]);
        console.log("y:", source.data['y'][selectedIndex[i]]);
    }
""")

taptool = p.select(type=TapTool)
source.selected.js_on_change('indices', callback)
show(p)
```

Comment: I am getting following error how do i solve this: AttributeError: 'PropertyValueDict' object has no attribute 'js_on_change'

Comment: Which version of Bokeh are you using?

Comment: For reference, `js_on_change` was added over two and a half years ago, in 0.12.4 If the version is truly that ancient, my first advice is to upgrade. If that is not possible, then the only option is to use the old style `.callback` property of the source itself as demonstrated here http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.12.3/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-selections

Comment: @Jasper Using Bokeh version 0.12.4

Comment: So that's the problem. Please upgrade or use the old documentation as bigreddot suggested.